# What's the colloquial opposite of "do me a solid"?

Tags: antonyms, colloquialisms

"Do me a solid" means doing something helpful for a friend. (I'm going off of Urban Dictionary definition, which I assume is accurate).

What would be a good colloquialism to describe the opposite of that phrase? E.g. a friend (someone who you expect to do you a solid) does to you something unhelpful or worse.

Comment: "Eff you over," most likely.

Comment: He *dissed* you. Basically, it's a casual verb of disrespect, but much more versatile. But please add a fill-in-the-blank sentence, so you get answers and not just opinions.

Comment: The obvious one is 'betray', but not really a colloquialism.

Comment: "Did me a dirty" or just "Did me dirty" fits the style and tone.

Comment: Obviously, he did you a liquid.  And it was a gas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of such phrases,
just as there is a spectrum of severity of the dirty deed. 
A fairly mild one is ***[he went behind my back](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+behind+back):***

> to do something that is kept a secret from someone affected by it.

Or ***[he upstaged me](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/upstaged):***

> To divert attention or praise from; force out of the spotlight:
>   *a vice president who repeatedly tried to upstage the president.*

A somewhat more severe one is ***[he pulled the rug out from under me](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+the+rug+from+under):***

> to suddenly take away important support from someone:
>   *The school pulled the rug from under the local team
>   by making them pay to practice in the school gym.*

The harshest one that that springs to mind is
***[he stabbed me in the back](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stab+in+the+back):***

> to betray someone
>   to do something secretly to harm someone:
>   *A lot of women in this business
>   think they have to stab each other in the back to get ahead.*

Comment: "upstaged" definitely doesn't fit. "stabbed in the back" seems closest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

He **did me a disservice**

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disservice)

> : something that harms or damages someone or something
>
> full definition: ill service; an unhelpful, unkind, or harmful act

Comment: This is somewhat correct in meaning but not quite what I'd call a colloquialism?

Comment: @DVK ~ may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it'll help others who search for a similar question. I've heard the term used plenty of times and while it's not slang it still falls under colloquial I would say (I'd even go so far as to say it's more standard usage than the above overly-dramatic examples. To stab someone in the back sounds like something a sitcom would use).